# DotNetNuke modal popup dialog boxes get wrong styling

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have an old DNN site that has been upgraded several times, from 5.6.2, through 6.2.5, 6.2.8, 7.0.5 and now is on 7.0.6. Most everything works well, but the popup modal dialog boxes (e.g. the Settings dialog box) look strange. specifically, the size is very narrow for my browser window. If I just click on the resize control on the lower right, it pops up to a normal size. Also, the close and maximize controls on the upper right are cropped, i.e. overflow is set to hidden. I can see from the Chrome Developer Tools that at least the 'overflow' css style is being set to hidden in the element.style style rule. I am not sure where this is coming from. I suspect that somehow this is due to the skin being an old, non-responsive skin, which I don't know much about. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to get these looking right? It's kind of annoying when I am working on the site.

Thanks.

EDIT: Added the screen shot. I have circled the cropped controls in the upper right, and you can see that the dialog box is only about 1/3 the width it should be. Thanks for your time in helping me on this issue. 
[image: DNN Error]

Comment: Why upgrade DNN and not upgrade the skin. It's like dressing a model in rags at the pageant and expecting them to win. If you don't want to spend money on a new skin, then use one of the default skins that come with DNN (ie. DarkKnight, Gravity) as your foundation and then customize to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. You make a valid point. We have a custom skin and I am in the process of upgrading it.

Comment: I actually switched the home page to the Dark Knight home page skin just to test it and that didn't fix the problem, so I am still looking...

Comment: It might be helpful if you post a screenshot so we can all see what you are seeing

Comment: I thought I'd post my solution and some observations. As my site didn't have a lot of database entanglement, i.e. it was purely an informational site, I just went and redid the site on a fresh install of DNN7, and it worked nicely. Until I wanted to use the jQuery tabs. Once I added the reference to "../jquery-ui.css" the styling on these pop up boxes started to look wrong. Haven't delved too deeply into it, but it sure looks like a conflict in jQuery UI.